# Most efficient way to apply operation on each element of Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Assume I have a function which takes a numpy array of shape `(m, k)` and I want to apply that function on each element of numpy array of shape `(n, m, k)`.
Naive approach is to iterate through the given numpy array and append the transformed element to an empty numpy array of shape `(0, m, k)`

```
result = np.empty(shape=(0, m, k))
for element in elements:
    result = np.append(result, [some_operation(element)], axis=0)
```

What's the efficient way to apply some, let's say, "operation" on numpy array of shape `(n, m, k)`? I guess there is a more "numpy" approach.

Many thanks.

Comment: List append is more efficient

Comment: Many numpy functions and methods can work with 3d array, but without knowing what's in your function we can't suggest a way of doing that.  So the most general way is to iterate on that first dimension, and collect the results.  If `some_operation` is complex it enough the iteration mechanism doesn't matter much; it's calling `some_operation `n` times that will take up most time.  But `np.append` is the least efficient; list append is better, or assignment to `result[element, :,:]`.

Comment: ```list(map(f, array))``` is marginally faster than the ```list.append``` loop, particularly for very large arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) is the most appropriate function for this

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful!